Generate a SQL string containing UNION and JOIN recursively
I am trying to generate a SQL string recursively that would contain UNION and JOIN using Python.
Below are the conditions:

Number of columns would be determined from a variable. If v = 2 the number of columns would be 3, with 1st one would always be fixed. If v = 3 the number of columns would be 4 with 1st one would always be fixed.

In each UNION block the number of join : number of columns - 1. And this would be increasing in numbers in each UNION block till the time the loop reaches v-1.

Number of UNION : v-1

Number of columns that would take NULL value (i.e. null as) in  each UNION block : v-1. And this would keep on decreasing like v-2,v-3 in each subsequent UNION block till it reaches 0


With the above two conditions let me show the desired output.
v = 2
tables = ['t1','t2'] #<---number of tables would be fixed

Now the desired output would be the sql string as :
select 
   a.col_1    #<---This would be fixed
  ,a0.col_2   
  ,null as col_3
from t1 a 
  left join t2 a0
  on a.col_1 = a0.col_1 and a0.level = 1
union all
select 
   a.col_1
  ,a0.col_2
  ,a1.col_3   #<----the null is being replaced by actual column col_3
from table1 a
  left join t2 a0 
  on a.col_1=a0.col_1 and a0.level = 1
  left join t2 a1   #<----please observe that same table t1 is being aliased differently
  on a.col_1 = a1.col_1  and a1.level = 2

Now what I have worked:
Approach Updated
tables = ['t1','t2']
lvl = 3
std_cols = ['parent','node'] #<-- This two also be fixed 
cols_select = ", ".join(['NULL AS col_{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(1,lvl)])

##Generating columns dynamically within UNION block##
cols=''
for i in range(lvl):
if i>0:
    cols =cols+ 'a{}.{}'.format(i+1,std_cols[1]) + ' AS col_{},'.format(i+1)
else:
    cols = ','+cols
print(cols[:-1])    

##Generating 'join' dynamically within UNION block
join_s = ''
for i in range(lvl):
  if i>0:
    join_s = join_s + ' left join {} a{}'.format(tables[1],i+1) +' on c.{}= a{}.{} and a{}.level={}'.format(std_cols[0],i+1,std_cols[0],i+1,i+1)
print(join_s) 

#Combining#
sql_i=''
sql_n =''
for i in range(lvl):
  if i==0:
    sql_i= sql_i +  'select c.{},'.format(std_cols[0]) + 'r.{} AS col_{},'.format(std_cols[1],i+1) + cols_select + ' from {} c'.format(tables[0]) +\
            ' left join {} r'.format(tables[1]) + ' on c.{}=r.{} and r.level={}'.format(std_cols[0],std_cols[0],i+1)
 elif i>0:   
    sql_n = sql_n + 'select c.{}'.format(std_cols[0]) + cols[:-1] + ' from {} '.format(tables[0]) +\
              join_s
 else:
    sql_n = sql_n + 'wip

But this approach is not working.

Join and Column part is not happening recursively. E.g. if lvl = 3, the joining string should be like below:
a1.col_1,NULL AS col_2,NULL as col_3 a1.col_1,a2.col_2, NULL as col_3 a1.col_1,a2.col_2,a3.col_3

Not able to include UNION part



What is your actual question? Have you looked at libraries like SQL Alchemy, which already solve this type of problem really well?

I have provided the actual output I am looking for. Essentially I trying to generate  a sql statement that would create a hierarchy dynamically. Can sqlalchemy do that?

Sounds like you want to check if your target RDBMS supports recursive common table expressions.

Actually I am currently working on databricks and it doesn't support recursive CTE. However, that part has been taken care of. But ultimate thing is generating the above sql string. Hence,  there is no target RDBMS.
